# Allowing users to choose between two sort options in a view

Tags: views, users

I have a view of user accounts.

I want to allow visitors to the site to choose to **sort**this view by login date or by account creation date in a view (Views 3, Drupal 7).

It's easy to expose the sort operator to users, but is there a way to let users select which sort is applied first (creation date or login date)?

I thought about just cloning the view, and then changing the sort on the second view and linking them together, but if possible I would like to avoid duplication.

Comment: how about sortable headers? I don't know if it goes two levels though

Comment: @Geoff For this view, I'm using Views Fluid Grid to manage the display (the view shows user profiles, and I'm using fluid grid because it works responsively), so unfortunately the sortable table headers won't help me, but that's a good idea.

Comment: the next option I might look at is a custom form inserted into the views header that creates the search url and refreshes the page. This way you could customise the layout and behaviour of the form and set the url appropriately

Comment: You could probably do that with https://www.drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters to accomplish this, I've combined two sorts together that way before, one selected with Ajax refreshing sort, then having the secondary sort tied in with the same. I would checkout the handbook links on that page for more direction, they have some pretty extensive recipes there that you could use as a base to start from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with [Better Exposed Filters](https://drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters). I've combined two sorts together that way before, one selected with Ajax refreshing sort, then having the secondary sort tied in with the same. I would checkout the handbook links on that page for more direction, they have some pretty extensive recipes there that you could use as a base to start from.

[handbook page for further reference](https://www.drupal.org/node/766974)